# Raising negative base numbers to decimal power using SQL Server POWER function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I ran through an error using the `POWER` function.

Below is the arithmetic formula that I am trying to do in my query.

```
growth rate = ((presentnetincome/pastnetincome) ^ (1/(presentyear-pastyear+ 1))) - 1
```

Below is the query that I have

```
WITH i AS
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        stockid,
        first_value([year]) over (partition by stockid order by [year]) AS year_first,
        first_value([year]) over (partition by stockid order by [year] desc) AS year_last,
        first_value(netincomeaftertax) over (partition by stockid order by [year]) AS netincome_first,
        first_value(netincomeaftertax) over (partition by stockid order by [year] desc) AS netincome_last
    FROM 
        incomestatements i
)
SELECT 
    stockid, 
    POWER(netincome_first / CAST(netincome_last AS FLOAT), 0.2) - 1 AS growthRate 
FROM i
```

However, I get an error

> An invalid floating point operation occurred

when the row's `netincome_first` is a negative number since they recorded a `NET LOSS` that `year`.

Are there any workarounds to this situation? Kindly help me investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Code corrected.  Please try now.

Comment: Answer updated.  Please try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH i AS ( SELECT DISTINCT stockid,
                   FIRST_VALUE( [year] ) OVER ( PARTITION BY stockid ORDER BY [year] ) AS year_first,
                   FIRST_VALUE( [year] ) OVER ( PARTITION BY stockid ORDER BY [year] DESC ) AS year_last,
                   FIRST_VALUE( netincomeaftertax ) OVER ( PARTITION BY stockid ORDER BY [year] ) AS netincome_first,
                   FIRST_VALUE( netincomeaftertax ) OVER ( PARTITION BY stockid ORDER BY [year] DESC ) AS netincome_last
            FROM incomestatements i )
SELECT stockid,
       SIGN( netincome_last -
                 netincome_first ) *
           ( POWER( ABS( ( netincome_last -
                                netincome_first ) /
                             netincome_first
                       ) + 1,
                       1 / ( year_last -
                               year_first )
                  ) - 1 ) AS growthShrinkageRate
```

Firstly, the given formula has an error in it, namely that `presentyear - pastyear + 1` should read `presentyear - pastyear`.  To illustrate, please consider starting with `$200.00` in the year `2012`, then consider this amount tripling / growing by `200%` in `2013` to `$600.00`, and this amount again tripling to `$1800.00` in `2014`.  We know that the growth rate is `200%` for both years.

If we use the given formula of...

```
( ( presentnetincome / pastnetincome ) ^ ( 1 / ( presentyear - pastyear + 1 ) ) ) - 1
```

... we get...

```
( ( 1800 / 200 ) ^ ( 1 / ( 2014 - 2012 + 1 ) ) ) - 1 = ( 9 ^ ( 1 / 3 ) ) - 1 = 1.080...
```

... instead of the `2` that we expect.  If you drop the `+ 1` from the formula, we instead get...

```
( ( 1800 / 200 ) ^ ( 1 / ( 2014 - 2012 ) ) ) - 1 = ( 9 ^ ( 1 / 2 ) ) - 1 = 2
```

Thus we can correct the formula to...

```
( ( presentnetincome / pastnetincome ) ^ ( 1 / ( presentyear - pastyear ) ) ) - 1
```

This formula will give the correct answer if both numbers are positive and the more recent is larger than the former.

If the values are both negative and the more recent is smaller (such as with `$-200.00` followed immediately by `$-1,800.00`, i.e. if a loss has been taken, the same result is received as if the numbers had both been positive and the latter larger, such as with `$200.00` followed by `$1,800.00`.  Both cases yield the same number, but the former reflects a rate of *loss*, i.e. negative growth.

If one of the values is negative then the formula will try to calculate the root of a negative number, which in half of all cases won't work with real numbers (the sort that we are using here) and in the other half would give a real, but wrong, number.

Thus a modified statement will need to be developed that will be able to handle all combinations of negative and positive amounts.

The single adapted formula I developed is...

```
SIGN( netincome_last -
          netincome_first ) *
    ( POWER( ABS( ( netincome_last -
                        netincome_first ) /
                      netincome_first
                ) + 1,
                1 / ( year_last -
                        year_first )
           ) - 1 )
```

If you would prefer it in a single line, it is...

```
    SIGN( netincome_last - netincome_first ) * ( POWER( ABS( ( netincome_last - netincome_first ) / netincome_first ) + 1, 1 / ( year_last - year_first ) ) - 1 )
```

The first point to note is that there is a pair of subtractions based on `netincome_first` and `netincome_last`.  This is to be expected as to measure growth you will sooner or later have to measure the *difference* between two values.

Secondly, the first part of our formula is used to indicate the direction of the change in `netincome_last` from `netincome_last`.  Here `SIGN()` will return `-1` if the number is negative and `1` if it positive.  When we multiply this number by the *magnitude* of the change we will be able to indicate if growth or loss has occurred and the size of that change.

Thirdly, the first argument of `POWER()` is...

```
ABS( ( netincome_last -
           netincome_first ) / netincome_first ) + 1
```

This formula measures the how many times larger `netincome_last` is in relation to the size of `netincome_first` for the number of periods covered, irrespective of whether or not growth or loss has occurred and what the signs of `netincome_first` and `netincome_last` are.

We add `+ 1` to the result of the division to compensate for the loss of `1` value of `netincome_first` caused by calculating the difference

To illustrate, for `netincome_first = 200` and `netincome_last = 1800` it gives...

```
ABS( ( 1800 - 200 ) / 200 ) + 1      = ABS( 1600 / 200 ) + 1   = ABS( 8 ) + 1  = 8 + 1 = 9
```

For `netincome_first = 200` and `netincome_last = -1400` it gives...

```
ABS( ( -1400 - 200 ) / 200 ) + 1      = ABS( -1600 / 200 ) + 1 = ABS( -8 ) + 1 = 8 + 1 = 9
```

For `netincome_first = -200` and `netincome_last = 1400` it gives...

```
ABS( ( 1400 - ( -200 ) / -200 ) + 1  = ABS( 1600 / -200 ) + 1  = ABS( -8 ) + 1 = 8 + 1 = 9
```

For `netincome_first = -200` and `netincome_last = -1800` it gives...

```
ABS( ( -1800 - ( -200 ) / -200 ) + 1 = ABS( -1600 / -200 ) + 1 = ABS( 8 ) + 1  = 8 + 1 = 9
```

The second argument of `POWER()` is the inverse of the number of periods covered.  For instance, if the above examples were for the period of `2012` through to `2014` then we would be considering 2 periods (2 years).  In each of these periods the nett income would have tripled, i.e. increased to `3` times each previous level.  We can calculate this value by finding the square root of `9`, i.e. by finding `9 ^ ( 1 1=/ 2 )`.

A value is said to have grown by a rate equal to how any times larger it is subtract one.  For example, where it increases to `3` times its previous level it is said to have a growth rate of `2` (i.e. it has grown `200%`).  Hence the `- 1` just after the `POWER()` calculation.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Oops - please hold.